# Derive the equation of a circle in complex notation with its center at $(3,-6)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Question: Let $z=x+iy $. Using complex notation, find an equation of a circle with radius $5$ and center $(3,-6) $.

The answer seems simple to derive, but I'm curious as to whether or not there is more that must be done to establish the equation than what I have accomplished.

The circle with the above information can be constructed from the equation

$$(x-3)^2+(y+6)^2=25$$

which implies that

$$\sqrt {(x-3)^2+(y+6)^2}=5$$

Therefore from the definition of the modulus of a complex number, we have

$$z=(x-3)+i (y+6)$$

However, I fail to see how we might use the $z $ in the first sentence of this post.

Comment: In your last sentence everything falls apart. $z = x + iy \ne (x-3) + i(y+6)= z - 3 + 6i$ so that just doesn't make any sense.  You aren't trying to solve for a single value of z.  You want an equation for which the solutions are the points of a circle.  $\sqrt{(x-3)^ + (y+6)^2} = 5$ is such an equation.  Can you express that in terms of z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of circle with radius $r$ centered at $(w,u)$:  All points, $z$ of the complex plane where the distance from $z$ to $w + iu$ equals $r$.  Or in other words: all $z$ where $|z - (w + ui)| = r$.

So the solution is $|z - (3 - 6i)| = 5$.  That's all there is to it.

Now if $z = x+iy$ then $|z - (3-6i)| = 5 \iff (x-3)^2 + (y+6)^2 = 25 \iff x^2 - 6x + y^2 + 12y + 20 = 0$ but those are three ways of saying the same thing.

So you can say:

Circle =$\{z \in \mathbb C| |z - (3-6i)| = 5\}$

$= \{z = x+yi \in \mathbb C| (x-3)^2 + (y+6)^2 = 25\}$

$= \{z = x+yi \in \mathbb C|x^2 - 6x + y^2 + 12y + 20 = 0\}$

I honestly have no idea which solution you text wants.  If it were my class I'd want simply want $\{z \in \mathbb C| |z - (3-6i)| = 5\}$.

I'd really like to get my students out of the mindset that complex numbers are some kind of game where we mix around the "real" real numbers.  Complex numbers *are* numbers and the circle *is* just the numbers that are 5 away from $3 - 6i$.

Then again, maybe the point is to give the students practice in calculate $|z| = \sqrt{re(z)^2 + im(z)^2}$ in which case... I don't know what your texts wants.

====

Maybe ... your text wants:

$(x-3)^2 + (y+6)^2 = 25$

$(y+6)^2= 16 - x^2 + 6x$

$y = -6 \pm \sqrt{16 -x^2 + 6x}$

So $z = x + (-6 \pm \sqrt{16 -x^2 + 6x})i$ where $-2 \le x \le 8$.

That might be what your texts wants but ... I'm not sure.

Comment: `I'd really like to get my students out of the mindset that complex numbers are some kind of game where we mix around the "real" real numbers.` +1 for that. As far as pedagogy, I believe one early confusion may be that it's straightforward to translate an equation such as $|z|=1$ in cartesian form $x^2+y^2=1$, but it's less obvious how to translate back, say, $x y =1$ to complex form, and the answer $z^2 - \bar z^2 = 4 i$ is unexpected at first.

Answer (score 0):

Develop the idea (the proof): it is

$$|z-3+6i|=5$$

Answer (score 0):

In the complex plane, a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin has the simple equation

$$|z| = 5$$

Where $z = x + iy$ and $|z|=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. We can transform this equation from being centered at the origin, to being centered at the point $3-6i$ by doing the following:

$$|z - (3-6i)| = 5$$

By substituting $z=x+iy$ into this expression, and using the definition of $|z|$ you will obtain the formula for a circle in the $xy$ plane of radius $5$ centered at the point $(3,-6)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it backwards.

Starting with the idea that the distance between $x+iy$ and $3-6i$ is $5$ we have

\begin{equation}
\vert x+iy - (3-6i)\vert=5
\end{equation}

or, rearranging terms

\begin{equation}
\vert x-3 +(y+6)i \vert=5
\end{equation}

thus

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y+6)^2 }=5
\end{equation}

and finally the sought result

\begin{equation}
(x-3)^2+(y+6)^2=25
\end{equation}